# Sammy.js routing: How to wait for a library to be loaded before routing

Tags: javascript, routes, sammy.js

I am currently building a Single Page App based on Google Cloud Endpoints (REST Api) which uses Sammy.js for routing.

### Introduction

To be able to use Endpoints I need to load a Google javascript Library, by adding the following script tag at the end of the HTML page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

And In the "init" callback function, I have to load my Endpoint. Pls see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js for more details.

I have a Sammy route which displays a list of items coming from the Endpoint, through:

```
this.get('#/listAllItems', function () {
   listItems();  // function which calls the Endpoint and displays the results
});
```

### The problem

When I call this route from a button (or menu item) in the page, there is no problem, since the Google javascript Library is already loaded, as well as the Endpoint.

However, when I call this route directly via the browser's address bar, I get a 500 Error because the javascript Library didn't have time to load before the routing is triggered.

```
body 500 Error get /page.html#/listAllItems gapi.client is undefined
```

I found a solution by waiting the library (and the Endpoint) to be loaded before calling the Endpoint with the code below. But I don't find that very elegant and there are probably some better/more efficient ways to handle this problem.

```
this.get('#/listAllItems', function () {
  function checkGapi() {
    if ((gapi.client) && (gapi.client.myEndpointApi)) {
      listItems();
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(checkGapi, 50);
    }
  }
  checkGapi();
});
```

Any suggestion would be very welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking Sammy.run() when all apis are loaded should do the trick. E.g.

```
var app = Sammy(...);
function init() {
   app.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does work. To be complete note that the Sammy.run() has to be called as a a callback function of the of Endpoint loading, like:
         function init() {
            var ROOT = 'https://yourendpoint.appspot.com/_ah/api';
            gapi.client.load(
                    'myEndpointApi',
                    'v1',
                    function() {
                        app.run();
                    },
                    ROOT);
        }